# What is the difference between 'implements' keyword and 'extends' keyword in dart?

Tags: dart

I couldn't understand the difference between these two keywords.

By using **extends** we can get features from parent class. I think **implements** does that too.

First I thought the difference is overriding methods but with **extends** I can do that.(I might be wrong)

Is the difference of these two keywords about overriding methods or what? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extends` means we get the implementation of a given class and we can then override members if we want our own implementation for certain variables or methods. You can also add new variables and methods.

`implements` means you get nothing from the class you implement from. But you promise that your class will be compatible with the interface of the class you are implementing. So no, you are not getting any implementation from the super class and you need to implement everything or declare your class `abstract`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you don't mind, can I ask: "What is interface?"

Comment: @Berke When talking about interface in this context it means the description of what methods, variables (and properties) a class are made of. See it as the structure of the class without the specific implementation.